# TreeSet and compareTo() method. Single sort or multiple sorts

Tags: java, hashset, compareto, treeset

Im currently working on a program, where im using a `TreeSet` to store unique keys. I'm using a TreeSet, because I want them sorted.

As of now, I have been making a TreeSet object, and added the strings one-at-a-time, when needed.

```
TreeSet set = new TreeSet();
set.add("How");
set.add("Are");
set.add("You");
```

Supposedly, the TreeSet uses the `compareTo` method in the `Compareable interface`, to sort the strings. That would mean that the TreeSet would have to do a sort each time I add a String to it.

Now my question is this: Would it be more efficient to create a `HashSet` and then create the `TreeSet` after `all strings` are added to the HashSet?

```
TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>(set);
```

My thoughts are going about whether the TreeSet would only need to do a single sort that way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No; you're misunderstanding BSTs.

Comment: `TreeSet` doesn't need to sort every time it inserts a string. More likely, it uses `compareTo` to figure out whether to take the left or right subtree when traversing the tree to insert the new element.

Comment: Imagine you have a bookshelf, where all the books are sorted in alphabetical order.  If you buy a new book, and want to put it on the shelf in the right place, do you have to re-sort all the books that are already there?

Comment: And moreover, creating a TreeSet from a HashSet will simply add all the keys one by one anyway.

Comment: I see your point, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TreeSet` is a [Self-balancing binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_tree). That means it will do `log(n, 2)` comparisons for each insert. It makes no difference if you add the elements independently or create the `TreeSet` from another collection.

Comment: I see the point - I'll continue programming now. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It won't make any difference as it internally calls the "addAll()" method, which in turn, **adds one element at a time**.

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<? extends E> e = c.iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
        if (add(e.next()))    //< -- Add one element at a time
           modified = true;
    }
    return modified;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentSkipListSet might offer better performance, depending.

This is based on an implementation of a sorted [SkipList](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). Asymptotic performance is O(log n) like a TreeSet, but it is supposed to be faster in general, and more storage-compact.  Plus, java includes the [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) already!

It might very well be faster to create the skiplist list from a sorted arraylist, depending on the implementation.  Bulk additions are usually faster than one-by-one (depending on the implementation).  The TreeSet represents something of an exception. Profile and find out!